# Open Office Communicator from Web page

Tags: javascript, outlook, lync, office-communicator

Is there a way (html or JavaScript preferred, but VBScript, Flash, Silverlight ok too...) to open an application like Office Outlook, Office Communicator or Lync directly from a Web page?

I don't need to start an e-mail or open a chat with a specific user, but rather access the application's general menu.

Of course, a user could directly open the application from his/her desktop menu. But the purpose is to have a Web page that provides some context and guides the user to the right tool depending on the needs.

Comment: If it was the web would be an insecure place.

Comment: @OlofEdler I don't get your comment. For example you can start an e-mail by clicking on a mailto: link, this is very common.

Answer (score 1):

Lync does have some command-line parameters you can call, which will activate Lync, provided it is installed on the machine.

TechNet has the full list [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376.aspx) - however, they all perform some action, none of them just activate Lync.

The closest thing I could find was the `callto` function - which doesn't initiate a call, but opens the dialog. It seems to be the call that "does the least":

`callto:sip:user@domain.com`

I've tested that you can call this from the Start > Run window. Therefore, I think you should be OK to include this as a HREF link: especially if you are running the page in a trusted zone (as I assume this is an intranet application).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately this is my issue, trying not to perform any specific action.

Comment: I don't think there's anything else which Lync specifically provides to help you with this. I don't know if JavaScript can help you here... I notice that the Lync client process (communicator.exe) has a mutex on it, so that if you open another instance, it will instead switch focus to the existing instance. You might be able to use that to help? Or hardcode the link to the exe as a file:// if you're sure you know where it is?